# Tomcat session timeout in 1 minute

Tags: tomcat, web.xml, session-timeout, httpsession

I have a web application that has a timeout of 1 minute in its web.xml but it never times out for this value.It does timeout for other values such as 5,9,10 or 25 minutes but never for 1 minute. Is this a minimum session timeout restriction on Tomcat 8?

```
    <!-- Session Configuration --> <session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout> </session-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, in my case is a global configuration, try to change it TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml